# Why do I get an error trying to print out a list one way vs the other?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, range

if you have a list for ex:

```py
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

and you want to print it out, what is the difference between:

```py
for letter in list:
    print(letter)

for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
```

i think the first approach has provided me with more errors but I am fairly new to python, please explain. thank you.

Comment: They result in the same output. The first approach is preferred in Python because it's more concise and idiomatic. It directly iterates over the elements themselves, which makes the code easier to understand and less error-prone. The second approach should generally be avoided unless you have a specific reason to work with indices directly, such as when you need the index for some other operations inside the loop.

Comment: What error do you get? your code does not error to me.

Comment: As there is no error, I closed the question and referred to a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

edit: fixed error in code

In the first one you shown, `i` is one of the items in the list whereas in the second one, `i` is a number.

Say for example you want to print out the index the item is in, and the item itself.

Here is what happens with the two different loops:

```py
your_list = ['a','b','c','d']

# first one

for i in your_list:
  print('the index of ' + i + ' is ' + your_list.index(i))


# second one

for i in range(0,len(your_list)):
  print('the index of ' + your_list[i] + ' is ' + i)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
the index of a is 0
the index of b is 1
the index of c is 2
the index of d is 3
the index of a is 0
the index of b is 1
the index of c is 2
the index of d is 3
```

however I would personally use the second one because if there were multiple `a`s in your list that would be a problem because then python will always return the first one in the list

PS:
try to not use `list` as your variable name because it is a built in python function

Comment: You should really be using `enumerate` if you need the index while looping

Comment: ok, i will learn more about it

Comment: If you use `index` to find the current position in the list, this will fail if you have duplicate values in the list.

Comment: @Matthias i have already said it in my post, which is why said i prefer the second one. please read....

Answer (score -1):

In first approach, you directly loop through the elements in the list, and each element is assigned to the variable letter one at a time.

In second approach, you use range(len(list)) to generate a sequence of indixes. Then, you use these indixes to access elements.

In your use case, First approach is more readable and chances of error are lesser.

Comment: Why would the chances of error be reduced? You haven't provided a justification to choose between the two approaches